# Emberjs - Creating a button using Views/Handlebar Helpers that focuses on itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, view, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars helper view that uses Em.Button(I know it's deprecated) to make a Deactivate Button that focuses on itself when the button appears. Clicking the button triggers the 'delete' action and focus-out uses an action to 'cancelDelete'

**The problem is** that handlebar helpers do not have a closing {{ / }} handlebar, preventing me from putting an text inside of the button, the button just ends up being an empty shell. **How do I give this button a text value?** OR **Is there an easier way of making this button without Em.Button?**

The **green check** will go to the answer that makes this button work.

The handlebar helper looks like this

```
{{delete-recordCategory class="" value=recordCategory focus-out="cancelDeactivate" insert-newline="cancelDeactivate"}}
```

In the view is where i added the focus and the click 'deactivate' action using

```
VpcYeoman.DeleteRecordCategoryView = Em.Button.extend(Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport, {
  click: function() {
    this.triggerAction({
      action: 'deactivateCategoryNow'
    }); // Sends the `save` action, along with the current context
        // to the current controller
  },
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().focus();
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('delete-recordCategory', VpcYeoman.DeleteRecordCategoryView);
```

The ember site suggested Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport as the way to add actions to this view.

Ember v. 1.0

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.Button` isn't just deprecated, it's been completely removed from newer versions. Definitely not something you want to keep around. Try writing your own. Here's a quick example of a component that might do what you want:

```
App.FocusButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Em.run.later(function() {
            this.$('button').focus();
        }.bind(this), 1);
    },

    actions: {
        click: function() {
            this.sendAction('click');
        }
    }
});
```

focus_button.hbs

```
<button {{action 'click' on='click' bubbles=false}}>
    {{yield}}
</button>
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
{{focus-button click='deactivateCategoryNow'}}
    Text Goes Here. Could be anything. <strong>Anything.</strong>
{{/focus-button}}
```

Comment: plus one! This one's great, it works ootb! I take it.